# Shrink imgs in a parrent div. The parrent div does not shrink with imgs

Tags: html, image, css

I am new with css and im stuck

I have a parent div containing 3 imgs. When I shrink the imgs the parrent div keeps original size. It shrink does shrink with the imgs.  How can I make sure that the div-element shrinks with img? Because i have a lot extra space after the last img.

I tried al the: block, inline-block, inline selectors.

I hope that one you can help me. Thank you for your time.

https://jsfiddle.net/7p479cfq/

```
    <div class="logos">
        <div class="dealer">Ekris</div>
        <img src="assets/img/bmw-logo.png" alt="" class="bmw-logo">
        <img src="assets/img/m-logo.png" alt="" class="m-logo">
        <img src="assets/img/i-logo.png" alt="" class="i-logo">
    </div>


div.logos  {
display: block;
background: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

.dealer {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: Arial, serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

img {
width: 20%;
height: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is an understanding of what's happening. Because you are specifying percentages on the width of the images, that percentage is a percentage of the parent element, not a percentage of the natural img size.

To solve this use pixel widths on the images and the space within their parent div disappears. Otherwise, if you want to fill the space then use percentages that add up to 100% - eg. 5 x images with 20% width each. Also, consider what width the text element will take up.

Comment: By the way, try putting width 50% width on the images and you'll see they take up exactly half of the parent div. Also, you don't need to apply a height percentage - the images should scale in proportion if you only specify the one dimension.

Comment: Sorry, original comment got lost. I think this makes a good comment but perhaps not an answer since it's untested. Also, it is possible to fix the issue even with percentages rather than needing to resort to fixed pixels.

Comment: I see you've updated the answer to be more specific which makes it a better answer.

Comment: I had tested it on the fiddle, but was still a little surprised myself that it would still add the space rather than collpasing around the image even with display:inline-block, thus my uncertainty to begin with. You might expect the container to collapse down around the smaller image because there's no padding etc. but of course that would lead to a circular depedancy of image/parent size and you end up with an image infinitely small.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the widths of the images but those percentages are calculated based on the parent. So, if you have your images set to 15% of the parent, then they are going to only take up 15%. For example, let's say the div is 300px, 15% of 300 is 45. You have three images. 3 * 45 = 135. Then, you have another div of an unspecified width that takes up some more space, but only as much as the text of it is. Let's say that for a short name, like you have, it only takes up 15px. So now you have 135 + 15 = 150. But your div is 300, so that leaves you with 150px of un-filled space.

It's not clear what you are looking to happen here, but, if you are looking to set your divs to take up an equal amount of whatever the parent is, you can just divide that equally. It's a little bit of a gamble if you don't set a width on the name div as well, but for arguments sake, let's say you want the four items to take up the same width: 100% / 4 = 25%.

I also added borders around the divs so you can see what is happening and left a commented out 40% so you could uncomment that to play around and get an idea of what is happening.

And because nothing is ever easy, because the images are inline there is some default spacing that comes with them because of font size. In the example I set the font-size of the parent to 0 to remove that as an unknown quantity and then just set the font-size on the div that actually has the text.

Again, it depends on what exactly you are looking for, but understanding what is going on might help you figure out how to achieve something else if this isn't what you had in mind.

https://jsfiddle.net/7p479cfq/1/

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.logos  {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  /* width: 40%; */
}

.dealer {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: Arial, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {   
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Chrome. When I deleted  `width: 20%;` from `img`, extra space disappeared.
I'm not sure why it happpened. I hope this solves your problem